# Combining multiple tables big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables in  different datasets:

table 1

| id | country | pos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | US | 1 |
| id2 | GB | 2 |
| id1 | ES | 3 |

table 2

| id | country | pos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | US | 1 |
| id2 | GB | 2 |
| id1 | ES | 3 |
| id1 | MX | 7 |

Im trying to get the following result which is an array of distinct countries per table (each as there own column)

| id | table1Country | table2Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | US, GB | US, ES, MX |
| id2 | GB | GB |

Here what i tried:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT country) AS table1Country FROM `table1` WHERE country IS NOT NULL GROUP BY id) as table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT country) AS table2Country FROM `table2` WHERE country IS NOT NULL GROUP BY id) as table2 
UNION ALL
```

it does produce an array but i dont know how to separate the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNION would join the data vertically, a `JOIN` like below joins them horizontally.

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` is needed, when the table differ much and have  ids that are not in both tables

```
SELECT COALESCE(table1.id,table2.id), table1Country ,  table2Country 
FROM
(SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT country) AS table1Country FROM `table1` WHERE country IS NOT NULL GROUP BY id) as table1 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT country) AS table2Country FROM `table2` WHERE country IS NOT NULL GROUP BY id) as table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` then apply a conditional aggregation to get data from both tables in a single row :

```
select id, MAX(table1Country) as table1Country, MAX(table2Country) as table2Country
from (
  SELECT id, case when source = 'table1' then STRING_AGG(country ORDER BY pos) end as table1Country,
             case when source = 'table2' then STRING_AGG(country ORDER BY pos) end as table2Country
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 'table1' as source FROM table1 WHERE country IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT *, 'table2' FROM table2 WHERE country IS NOT NULL
  ) a
  GROUP BY id, source
) b
group by id
```

I used here `STRING_AGG` to get countries separated by commas, as specified in the desired output.